# Postman GET options works but fails with cURL command line

Tags: api, curl, postman, spring-aop

I am running a spring application and when doing GET requests on POSTMAN I get my API response, see below
[image]

However, when I run a curl command I get a 307 Redirect error

[image]

I tried to dig into but could not solve it. Could be a proxy issue ?

Comment: You use different endpoints, in Postman, you use `/api/v1/posts` and un curl `/api/v1`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @pavelsaman, you're using different endpoints in Postman and your curl.

To avoid that and run the very same request in curl as in Postman, you can export your request from Postman as curl:

Click "Code", then select "cURL", copy the code, and paste it to your commandline:
[image]

You can find the documentation here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/